# How to remove the hyphens from the phone number

Tags: c#, jquery, regex

I have the phone number stored in the database in the '234-565-1233' format. I want to remove the hypens from this Following is the code i tried but nothing worked.'OncallDDl' hold the phone number value with hyphens.I want the value to be returned as 2345651233.And assign it back to the 'OncallDDL'. Can anyone hlpe me please

```
var str = OncallDDL.Text;
var newstr = str.Replace("/-/g",""); /error
var newStr = str.Replace(/-/g, ""); /error
var newStr = str.Replace("-", ""); /error
var newStr = str.Replace("\\D", ""); /error
```

Comment: `/error` isn't particularly helpful.  Exactly what error were you running into?

Comment: `string.Replace` does not take a `Regex` for parameter

Comment: i got this working by using var newstr = str.Replace("-",""); .Bi=ut how do i assign this value back to the OncallDDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

```
var str = OncallDDL.Text;
var newstr = str.Replace("-","");
```

Comment: Thanks i was using a space before str.Replace("-", ""); like this so got error

Comment: How to check if the phone number has hyphens or not

Comment: return s.Contains('-')

To check for hyphens

Comment: @Nethra use a check like if (str.indexOf("-") >= 0)